# How to disable the blinking cursor in the output window if i m using turbo cpp compiler?

Tags: c, time, cursor

I made a simple program to show the current date and time using some standard functions in turbo cpp.I want to know how can I turn of the blinking cursor from the output window. My current code is as follow :

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>

void main()
{
   time_t t;
   printf("Day and time \n\n");
   while(1)
   {
      time(&t);
      clrscr();
      printf("Day and time is \n%s",ctime(&t));
      delay(1000);

      if(kbhit())
          break;//breaks the infinite loop if any key is hit
  }

  getch();

}
```

Comment: You *really* ought to get a modern compiler. Why are people still using 20+ year old tools when there are modern versions freely available? I don't get it.

Comment: @JesperJuhl perhaps for the same reason so many people never wear new clothes. The machines required to run those modern compilers are not free.

Comment: @WeatherVane :  Perhaps, but a 16 bit compiler on a 32 bit OS is somewhat limiting - there are plenty of free 32 bit tools that will run happily on even 20 year old hardware (if it is still running).  It probably has more to do with low cost tools adopted long ago for courses presented by some academic institutions when tools were seldom free and a reluctance to develop new course material.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution to your problem is _setcursortype() function.

Ques. **What is _setcursortype() function and what functionality it provides to you?**

**Ans**- first, setcursortype() function is not ANSI/ISO C standard function.
         second,  It is defined in conio.h and provided with old compilers(like turbo c) and obviously not portable.

I explain all Functionalities provided by _setcursortype() in a simple c code.
And this code runs on my turboc so I hope it'll definately run on your own. :)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#iclude<conio.h> 

int main()
{

printf("Normal Cursor: "); getch();          /* Display the normal cursor */


_setcursortype(_NOCURSOR);
printf("No Cursor : "); getch();              /* Turn off the cursor */


_setcursortype(_SOLIDCURSOR);       
printf("Solid Cursor : "); getch();          /* Switch to a solid cursor */


_setcursortype(_NORMALCURSOR);         
printf("Normal Cursor: "); getch();          /* Switch back to the normal cursor */

return 0;
getch();
}
```

It also helps you to how to turn off or disable blinking cursor on console window of your turbo c.:)

Comment: thanks @ Weather Vane  for your helpful opinion for his point of view. :)

Comment: try first yourself...if you actually found  that  I helped you than I feel also great to help you in some way and  you can upvote or accept my answer too ali bhaijan :)

Comment: mension not bro..I'm always be there for help in c questions :)

Comment: I knew how to do this in visual studio but here I thought it was not possible so I asked my doubt . Our most of the Indian Schools and college teach C and CPP in turbo cpp dont know why :D

Comment: bhai scl and clgs me jo dikhta h wo hi bikta h.. turbo c is old one na..nd old is gold for our teachers..easy to teach .. :D